# How does one can be initiated with Mahamantra?

Tags: initiation

How does a non Vaishnava get initiated with hare Krishna Mahamantra? What  Vaishnava Acharyas are there in the world today who initiate people?

Comment: If you go to any ISKCON center they will initiate you